# Is there a viable cause of action for exposing someone of academic misconduct?

Tags: defamation

Is there a viable cause of action for exposing someone's academic misconduct from a country different than the one the exposed person lives and works.

For instance if you live in a European country, the exposed person also lives in a different European country and the site that exposes him is based in America, are the elements of defamation made out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A defames B, the fact that the parties live and work in different countries is not a bar to a defamation lawsuit. This is not changed when  platform C is headquartered in a third country. A choice of law question does arise, which is important because B can always sue A, but they might have a legally-better outcome if they sue in the defendant's jurisdiction (plaintiff-friendly rules) yet they might be concerned over the "home courts advantage". The EU has [a rule](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/ALL/?uri=CELEX%3A32007R0864) applying "to non-contractual obligations in civil and commercial matters" which expressly excludes "non-contractual obligations arising out of violations of privacy and rights relating to personality, including defamation" (there is no uniform EU answer). [This article](https://tlblog.org/multistate-defamation-cross-border-torts-and-choice-of-law/) touches on such considerations in transnational defamation.

Whether or not some specific content rises to the level of defamation depends on the actual facts (was there plagiarism, which is not a legally-defined category unlike copyright infringement), and the choice of law.

Comment: An accusation of plagiarism or other academic misconduct would probably be [defamation per se](https://www.findlaw.com/injury/torts-and-personal-injuries/what-is-defamation-per-se-.html) in jurisdictions that have that concept.